What is the weak derivative of the Dirichlet function?
From Wikipedia, it is explained like this:
The characteristic function of the rational numbers ${\displaystyle 1_{\mathbb {Q} }}$ is nowhere differentiable yet has a weak derivative. Since the Lebesgue measure of the rational numbers is zero,
$$\int 1_{\mathbb{Q}}(t)\varphi (t)dt=0$$
Thus $v(t)=0$ is a weak derivative of ${\displaystyle 1_{\mathbb {Q} }}$. Note that this does agree with our intuition since when considered as a member of an $L^p$ space,
${\displaystyle 1_{\mathbb {Q} }}$ is identified with the zero function.
I don't understand how they can deduce $v(t)=0$ from the above integral. Can someone explain to me specifically using the integration by parts formula, as defined by the weak derivative? Thank!

This follows by noticing that $\int (1_{\mathbb{Q}}) \phi~dt = \int 0\cdot \phi~dt$ for all $\phi$ so $1_{\mathbb{Q}} = 0$ in the sense of distributions.
